# みたいに vs のように? What suits best?

Tags: grammar

I came across the following, recently.

彼女が蛇口をあけ、僕の傷ついた前腕を氷　_______ 冷たい水の下へ導いた

It is said that the most suitable to fill the blank is のように. みたいに is also given as an option. Can someone please explain me why のように? Why not みたいに?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is simply because 「みたいに」 sounds too informal and conversational for the context, which does not sound informal at all.

「のように」, which is more formal than 「みたいに」, would fit far better there.

It is of importance to keep the overall level of formality/informality in any kind of writing/speech.

You would not use the phrase "kinda like" in an essay or part of a novel that describes a character's actions, would you?  I am not necessarily saying that 「みたいに」 sounds as informal as "kinda like", but you get my point.

Comment: Apart from the informality, are there any grammatical errors introduced, if I use みたいに? May be the usage of the particle に (which I feel like みたいな sounds much better)?

Comment: No, not at all.  This is not a grammar issue.  If grammar is all that counts, using みたいに is still grammatical.

Comment: Okay.. So what about replacing the に with な? Still it is grammatically okay?

Comment: No.  な will not work here because 氷みたいに/氷のように modifies the adjective 冷たい.　～～な can only modify a noun.